# access denied exception on changing the directory icon in java

Tags: java

I am trying to change icon of the directory.

```
File folder = new File("D:\\test\\test");
Wini ini = new Wini(folder);
String field = "C:\\Users\\Agnisys\\Downloads\\Hopstarter-Sleek-Xp-Basic-Files.ico" + ",0";
ini.put(".ShellClassInfo", "IconResource", field);
ini.store();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +H " + folder.getAbsolutePath());
```

But it shows me the exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: directory path (Access is denied)
```

I have provide all access permission to `c://programfiles//java` but still it occurred this exception. Any solution would be so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions does not mean that you are not allowed to access Java under `c://programfiles//java` but are missing the rights to either access `D:\\test\\test`or `C:\\Users\\Agnisys\\Downloads\\Hopstarter-Sleek-Xp-Basic-Files.ico` or are not allowed to modify `"D:\\test\\test`.

Verify that the user that you are executing java with has the needed rights:

- read & modify to `D:\\test\\test`
- read `C:\\Users\\Agnisys\\Downloads\\Hopstarter-Sleek-Xp-Basic-Files.ico`

Comment: yes i have already verify for both file and folder but still facing this problem